# Create a generic return type based on the value of parameter

Tags: typescript

Given that I have a function like this:

```
GetKeys([
  { name: 'MyFirstKey', value: 'string' }
  { name: 'MySecondKey', value: 123 }
]);
```

How do I dynamically take the value of `name` for each element in the array and use that as a key for a return type, and the type of value as the return type. Assuming the return type is:

```
export type TheReturnTypeThatIWantToDynamicallyGenerate = {
  MyFirstKey: string;
  MySecondKey: number;
}
```

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLrr2w) close enough?  Note that the return type has literal types for the property values, not just `string` and `number`.  I'm not sure how vital it is for it to infer literal types for the keys but not for the property values.  Let me know if this suffices and I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, I will present alternatives